# Increment logic to split Insert,update,delete from Full file

Tags: python, sql, etl, datastage

We are working on a project where we receive the file daily file of 90GB approx which consists of ~60M rows. The problem is they are sending the full file every day (90GB) which is inclusive of history of unchanged data as well as new data.

Now it is our task to split only the New inserts, Deletes, and Updates to separate files and load. How could we do this efficiently?

Tools used: Datastage and AWS( can be used ) if it is cost-efficient and gives a good performance. Final target to load the data into Snowflake.

Comment: Your question needs a better explanation of sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

tbh sounds like what you want to do is a merge from flat file:

https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/how-to-perform-a-mergeupsert-from-a-flat-file-staged-on-s3

and if your table has operations and not actual records just pick up the latest timestamp from table before you do this and apply all operations since that timestamp after the merge is complete